# using event for inserting to database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, events, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to find most occurred item in database. I already done this in one way but want to use events for this can any one help me to use events so I can understand about laravel events also the way i done was this insert to database when a link is clicked and selecting the data which occurred more than 2 times my code is like this function inserts when button is clicked and start downloading

```
public function song_download($url)
{
    $download   = DB::table('song_details')->select('song_location')->where('song_title',$url)->get();
    $path = 'songs/'.$download{0}->song_location.'.mp3';

    return response()->download($path);
}
```

When index page loads to show most popular content, I used a function like this.

```
public function index()
{
    $songs          = Song_detail::select()->latest()->get();
    $malayalamSongs = Mostpopular::select('song_id')->groupBy('song_id')->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 3')->get();
    return view('pages.index',compact('songs','malayalamSongs'));
}
```

Please help me to understand whether there is any best method than this using laravels events.

Comment: What do you actually want to use the event for?

Comment: when ever the count of song_id is increase mostpopular item should be updated

Comment: For something like that I would just put the logic for it in the controller as I assume it's just going to be a database update. The idea of events would be more suited for when you have multiple actions that need to take place (or at least you believe you will in the future). Otherwise, at this point I would suggest it's overkill. Where is your logic for the update by the way?

Comment: OK i got it now i have an example if have a webpage that has two sections one is most popular and other is most recent should i use events